# VueJS child component does not update v-model when toggling checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I created the following custom child component in VueJS 2 using Bootstrap Vue as a UI framework:

```html
<template lang="pug>
b-form-checkbox(
  :value="value.acceptTerms"
  @input="handleInput('acceptTerms', $event)"
  :disabled="disabled") Accept terms and conditions
</template>

export default {
  name: "RegistrationForm",
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    v: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    handleInput(key, value) {
      console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`);
      this.v.$touch();
      this.$emit("input", { ...this.value, ...{ [key]: value } });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The parent component passes the `v-model` like this:

```
registration-form(v-model="responseData" :v="$v.responseData" :disabled="!editMode")
```

The behavior I'm observing is, that the checkbox is clickable and toggles its state but the `v-model` does not change. The `console.log()` statement prints the value only once the form is loaded initially.

I also tried using `$event.target.checked` but this gives an error in the console that this is`undefined`.

According to the [Bootstrap Vue documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox#comp-ref-b-form-checkbox-events) the `@input` event uses `checked` as an argument but I can't see how I could use this in the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Right after having posted this question, I once again checked the docs and found that the following change to the template is the solution:

```html
<template lang="pug>
b-form-checkbox(
  :checked="value.acceptTerms"
  @input="handleInput('acceptTerms', $event)"
  :disabled="disabled") Accept terms and conditions
</template>
```

That is, I need to use `:checked` instead of `:value`.